# Separation of concerns and polymorphic design

Tags: c#

Let's say I'm trying to model what animals do and how animals look, and I want to keep the code for each animal separate and the code for actions/looks separate as well. How can I model this in C#?

This would be ideal:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class PaintingAnimals {
  class Animal {}
  class Cat : Animal {}
  class Dog : Animal {}

  static void Paint(Cat cat) { System.Console.WriteLine("Cat"); }
  static void Paint(Dog dog) { System.Console.WriteLine("Dog"); }
  static void Paint(Animal animal) { System.Console.WriteLine("Animal"); }

  public static void Main() {
    var animals = new List<Animal> {new Cat(), new Dog()};

    foreach (var animal in animals) {
      Paint(animal); // Always prints "Animal" not "Cat" or "Dog"
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I understand correctly, this code will only compile if `Paint` is defined as `Paint(Animal)`, not as `Paint(Cat)` or `Paint(Dog)` and therefore I can't split my code for each animal into different functions such that Dogs and Cats will be painted differently.

Comment: There are way to many ways to do that... As option check out [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) - possibly implemented with `Piant((dynamic)animal)` and full set of `Paint(Cat)`... overrides.

Comment: don't understand what you mean  "same code for both objects", can you show your Paint function?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Visitor pattern! Useful pointer, thank you.

Comment: @AwakeningByte "same code" means "same function" i.e. no dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @user12341234 I am not sure what your question is. If your paint method accepts type Animal, then your code would work the way you have it.

Comment: I got his question here, he wants the Paint function knows how to paint different kind of animals instead of have it define in types itself. am I right, @user12341234?

Comment: The main problem is that Paint() should do different things for Cats and Dogs.

Comment: @KhanhTO after investigating @AlexeiLevenkov's suggesting, 2 overloaded methods work, but only in conjunction with the `dynamic` keyword in the foreach loop

Comment: What about using the `is` keyword? `if (animal is Cat) { do something } else { do something else }`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not call a method with the animal as parameter, but rather call a method ON the animal:

```
static void Main() {
  var animals = new List<Animal> {new Cat(), new Dog()};

  foreach (var animal in animals) {
    animal.Paint();
  }
}
```

Each concrete Animal class will implement the Paint method as it sees fit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution seems to force me to keep my `Paint` code in the same place as my other code... All in side the Cat/Dog class.

Comment: The `Paint` really belongs inside each specific class. Otherwise, you'll need a growing `if` or `select` statement in the "global" Paint method to cater to each different possible Animal.

Comment: A growing if statement is one solution, though it forces tight coupling of modules. In other languages dynamic dispatch or parametric polymorphism are alternatives that might work. I was wondering if there was another way in C# that didn't need a giant switch.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why having all the `Cat` code in the `Cat` class, and so on, would be a problem. Could you expand on this?

Comment: Have you ever met a cat that knew how to paint itself? Cats know how to sleep and purr, but really it should be the job of a painter to paint the cat, I think.

Comment: Uuuh? Now you're being facetious. Pull that code out of the Cat then, and place it in a Painter<Cat>. Like we say, there's more than a way to skin a cat.

Comment: @LucMorin So you suggesting that for every operation each class must implement virtual method? This is know not to scale well... Usual sample - saving objects to multiple medium (text, binary,....).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm suggesting that having a single Paint method with a giant if/switch will certainly scale much worse than having each class Paint itself.

Comment: @LucMorin sorry, didn't mean to come off flippant, just that "Paint" is a meta-task, it's not something that a cat does, and in standard OO methodology the methods on the Cat class should only do things a cat would do.

Comment: @user12341234 no offense taken, I just found it rather amusing. While true that Paint is a meta task, the way you described the problem implied that it was still subclass specific enough to warrant a different implementation. I'm still not clear as to what you gain, unless a major part of the "painting" code is always the same. This is why I was thinking of using a Painter<T> class.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating @AlexeiLevenkov's suggestion, I've found the following code to do what I wanted:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class PaintingAnimals {
  class Animal {}
  class Cat : Animal {}
  class Dog : Animal {}

  static void Paint(Cat cat) { System.Console.WriteLine("Cat"); }
  static void Paint(Dog dog) { System.Console.WriteLine("Dog"); }
  static void Paint(Animal animal) { System.Console.WriteLine("Animal"); }

  public static void Main() {
    var animals = new List<Animal> {new Cat(), new Dog()};

    foreach (dynamic animal in animals) { // Uses "dynamic", not "var"
      Paint(animal); // Print's "Cat" and "Dog" respectively, not "Animal"
    }
  }
}
```

The key here is the use of `dynamic` in the foreach loop, that changes the type of each element from `Animal` to `Cat` and `Dog` respectively.